# How to set zdata for a Line3D object in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I would like to update a figure containing a Line3D object. To do this I would like to update the data for the line and then redraw the canvas.

For a Line2D object, the x and y values can be updated using "set_xdata" and "set_ydata". How do I set the zdata? Just using "set_zdata" gives an error..

Answer (score 4):

A Line3D object contains the method "set_3d_properties(zs=0, zdir='z')". This can be used to set the zdata:

```
#plot figure with line
f=pyplot.figure()
ax=f.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
mylines=ax.plot(xs,ys,zs)

#update figure with new x and z data
mylines[0].set_xdata(newxs)
mylines[0].set_3d_properties(newzs)
f.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: just fyi in 2023 (matplotlib version 3.5.1) I was able to get `.set_data_3d(x, y, z)` to work nicely, as well as `.set_data_3d(xyz)` where `xyz` is a 3xN array, but not `.set_3d_properties()`